# Apache Ignite .Net - Log4Net Integration

Tags: c#, .net, log4net, ignite

I created a logger in my .Net program and my objective is to integrate the log of ignite in my own logger.
In java i can reach that by integrate the library ignite - log4j but in .Net does not seem the same procedure.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle Ignite logs and integrate them with other systems by implementing `Apache.Ignite.Core.Log.ILogger` interface and setting `IgniteConfiguration.Logger` property.

Ignite provides integration with Log4Net and NLog out of the box.

See https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/logging for more details.

Comment: Thank you for you prompt response. So in order to reach the log of ignite, i have to import the ignite-log4j jar in class path of .net?

Comment: @AlessioR no, you don't have to bother with any Java things. If `IgniteConfiguration.Logger` property is set, Ignite will log only there (from Java and .NET code). Try it!

Comment: It works! I add the configuration that you told me! Thank you! But how can i raise the log from debug to info only for ignite? what i have to put in my log4net.config file?

Answer (score 0):

The current ignite version 2.4 supports it like that:

```
var config = new IgniteConfiguration()
{
    Logger = new Apache.Ignite.Log4Net.IgniteLog4NetLogger(),
};
```